# How to fix inf coordinate system of point cloud?

Tags: python, opencv, point-clouds, cloudcompare

Using OpenCvs Python library I processed a disparity map from [two rectified stereo images](https://cloudstore.zih.tu-dresden.de/index.php/s/zogn55AazXrFRG7). Afterwards I converted that map to 3D points using `cv2.reprojectImageTo3D()` and saved it as .ply. When I'm trying to open the point cloud in e.g. CloudCompare I get a "Global shift/scale" warning. The "Point in original coordinate system (on disk)" box says inf for x, y, z coordinates (see image).

[image: Global Shift/Scale Warning]

So it seems that I forgot some step(s) or did a mistake when generating the point cloud. I did:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv


ply_header = '''ply
format ascii 1.0
element vertex %(vert_num)d
property float x
property float y
property float z
property uchar red
property uchar green
property uchar blue
end_header
'''


def write_ply(fn, verts, colors):
    verts = verts.reshape(-1, 3)
    colors = colors.reshape(-1, 3)
    verts = np.hstack([verts, colors])
    with open(fn, 'wb') as f:
        f.write((ply_header % dict(vert_num=len(verts))).encode('utf-8'))
        np.savetxt(f, verts, fmt='%f %f %f %d %d %d ')


pcd_dir = "/some/path/points.ply"
imL = cv.imread("/path/to/left/frame0000.jpg", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
imR = cv.imread("/path/to/right/frame0000.jpg", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

stereo = cv.StereoBM_create(numDisparities = 16, blockSize = 11)
disparity = stereo.compute(imL, imR)

h, w = imL.shape[:2]
f = 0.8 * w
Q = np.float32([[1, 0, 0, -0.5 * w],
                [0, -1, 0, 0.5 * h],
                [0, 0, 0, -f],
                [0, 0, 1, 0]])

points = cv.reprojectImageTo3D(disparity, Q)
print(type(points))
print(points.shape)

colors = cv.cvtColor(imL, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
mask = disparity > disparity.min()
out_points = points[mask]
out_colors = colors[mask]
write_ply(pcd_dir, out_points, out_colors)
```

Expected output would be obviously a readable point cloud.

Comment: well yes, disparity maps aren't perfect. for some pixels, no good match could be found. for other pixels, the disparity is actually 0, meaning you found pixels corresponding to an object ***at infinity*** (a star, something at the horizon, ...). you can always prune/mask that stuff using `np.isfinite()` -- for debugging, look at the bare disparity map first.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to fix it with `np.ma.array(x, mask=np.isfinite(disparity))`.